# Struggling with chaining postgres db async/await promises to get a result sent to client (express)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, promise, async-await

I have spent a while looking around at similar problems online but I seem to be really struggling to wrap my head around this. I've reviewed a few sources online for help but was unable to apply the logic I seen to my own codebase, I'm hoping somebody out there might be able to help.

I'm running an express server with a pg Pool to handle DB logic.

I am able to successfully log out the information from within the pg.Pool logic however despite banging my head against multiple attempts I have been unable to successfully pass the data onto the clientside.

dbQueries.js

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database:process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
});

// Main function called in server.js
// step 1. fetches distinct name values from pg table
// step 2. fetches values to get full list of reviews for those distinct names
// step 3. does some data modification to make the data formatted for frontend usecase

const getFormattedReviews = async function(){
  console.log('Fetching all unique therapist review names.')

  const getDistinct = {
    name: 'distinct-reviews',
    text: 'SELECT DISTINCT therapist_name FROM reviews'
  };

  // step 1
  const res = await pool.query(getDistinct, (err, res) => {
    let data = []
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      // console.log(res.rows);
      data = res.rows.map(
        // step 2
        therapist => getSpecificTherapistReviews(therapist.therapist_name)
      )
    }
    console.log(`\n DEBUG3 - getFormattedReviews data: ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n`)
    return data;
  });
  return res;
}

const getSpecificTherapistReviews = async function(therapist_name){
  console.log(`Fetching reviews for: ${therapist_name}.`)

  const getSpecificTherapistReviews = {
    name: `${therapist_name}-reviews`,
    text: `SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE therapist_name LIKE '%${therapist_name}%'`
  };

  const res = await pool.query(getSpecificTherapistReviews, (err, res) => {
    let data = []
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      // console.log(res.rows);
      // step 3
      data = filteringDataForFrontend(res.rows);
    }
    console.log(`\n DEBUG2 - GetSpecificTherapistReviews ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n`)
    return data;
  });
  return res;
}

const filteringDataForFrontend = function(data){
  console.log(`Filtering Data for Frontend.`)

  // Based on length of the reviews array, each review = 1 object
  const total_reviews = data.length;

  // Underlying logic assumes consistent data across all entries for these values
  const therapist_name = data[0].therapist_name;
  const type = data[0].type;
  const image = data[0].image;
  const location = data[0].location;

  // Summing the rating values across multiple review entries
  const ratings = data.reduce((acc, obj) => ({
    rating_friendliness: acc.rating_friendliness + obj.rating_friendliness,
    rating_techniques: acc.rating_techniques + obj.rating_techniques,
    rating_progression: acc.rating_progression + obj.rating_progression,
    rating_cost: acc.rating_progression + obj.rating_progression,
    rating_listening: acc.rating_listening + obj.rating_listening,
    rating_overall: acc.rating_overall + obj.rating_overall
    })
  )

  // Placeholder as string, most likely restructure to an array of objects
  const comments = data.reduce ((acc, obj) => ({
      feedback_comments: acc.feedback_comments + obj.feedback_comments
    })
  )

  // Filtered data for returning
  const filteredData = {
    therapist_name,
    type,
    image,
    location,
    rating_friendliness: ratings.rating_friendliness / total_reviews,
    rating_techniques: ratings.rating_techniques / total_reviews,
    rating_progression: ratings.rating_progression / total_reviews,
    rating_cost: ratings.rating_cost / total_reviews,
    rating_listening: ratings.rating_listening / total_reviews,
    rating_overall: ratings.rating_overall / total_reviews,
    feedback_comments: comments.feedback_comments
  }
  console.log(`\n DEBUG 1 - filteredData -> ${JSON.stringify(filteredData)} \n`)
  return filteredData;
}

module.exports = {
  getFormattedReviews,
};
```

An ideal setup I would like to have on the server.js side of things running express would be:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const DB = require('./dbQueries.js');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8000;

app.get('/get-reviews', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await DB.getFormattedReviews();
  console.log(`data check ${data}`);
  res.send({data});
});
```

Currently the endpoint is logging 'data check undefined'.

DEBUG checks 1 & 2 successfully appear to log information, however I spotted that DEBUG 3 only logs `DEBUG3 - getFormattedReviews data: [{},{},{}]` so perhaps I'm doing something wrong around there?

Any help/insight appreciated.

Comment: Don't pass a callback to an async function that you expect to return a promise.

Comment: Also don't ignore errors, by logging them and then continuing without data as if nothing happened!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Abraham & @Labkovsky for the suggestions -> Ill review them properly during the week.

I managed to get the basic fuctionality up and running with this code - it likely needs some refactoring but for reference:

dbQueries.js

```
const getFormattedReviews = async function(){

  const getDistinct = {
    name: 'distinct-reviews',
    text: 'SELECT DISTINCT therapist_name FROM reviews'
  };

  const res = await new Promise(resolve => {
    pool.query(getDistinct, (err, res) => {
    let data = []
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      // console.log(res.rows);
      data = res.rows.map(
        async therapist => await getSpecificTherapistReviews(therapist.therapist_name)
      )
      // Promise.all(data).then(results => console.log(`\n DEBUG3 - getFormattedReviews data: ${JSON.stringify(results)} \n`))
    }
    Promise.all(data).then(results => resolve(results));
  });

});
  return res;
}

const getSpecificTherapistReviews = async function(therapist_name){
  // console.log(`Fetching reviews for: ${therapist_name}.`)

  const getSpecificTherapistReviews = {
    name: `${therapist_name}-reviews`,
    text: `SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE therapist_name LIKE '%${therapist_name}%'`
  };

  const res = await new Promise(resolve => {
    pool.query(getSpecificTherapistReviews, (err, res) => {
      let data = []
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
      } else {
        // console.log(res.rows);
        data = filteringDataForFrontend(res.rows);
      }
      // console.log(`\n DEBUG2 - GetSpecificTherapistReviews ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n`)
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
  return res;
}

const filteringDataForFrontend = function(data){
  // Based on length of the reviews array, each review = 1 object
  const total_reviews = data.length;

  // Underlying logic assumes consistent data across all entries for these values
  const therapist_name = data[0].therapist_name;
  const type = data[0].type;
  const image = data[0].image;
  const location = data[0].location;

  // Summing the rating values across multiple review entries
  const ratings = data.reduce((acc, obj) => ({
    rating_friendliness: acc.rating_friendliness + obj.rating_friendliness,
    rating_techniques: acc.rating_techniques + obj.rating_techniques,
    rating_progression: acc.rating_progression + obj.rating_progression,
    rating_cost: acc.rating_progression + obj.rating_progression,
    rating_listening: acc.rating_listening + obj.rating_listening,
    rating_overall: acc.rating_overall + obj.rating_overall
    })
  )

  // Placeholder as string, most likely restructure to an array of objects
  const comments = data.reduce ((acc, obj) => ({
      feedback_comments: acc.feedback_comments + obj.feedback_comments
    })
  )

  // Filtered data for returning
  const filteredData = {
    therapist_name,
    type,
    image,
    location,
    total_reviews,
    rating_friendliness: ratings.rating_friendliness / total_reviews,
    rating_techniques: ratings.rating_techniques / total_reviews,
    rating_progression: ratings.rating_progression / total_reviews,
    rating_cost: ratings.rating_cost / total_reviews,
    rating_listening: ratings.rating_listening / total_reviews,
    rating_overall: ratings.rating_overall / total_reviews,
    feedback_comments: comments.feedback_comments
  }

  // console.log(`\n DEBUG 1 - filteredData -> ${JSON.stringify(filteredData)} \n`)
  return filteredData;
}

module.exports = {
  getFormattedReviews,
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const DB = require('./dbQueries.js');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 8000;

app.get('/get-reviews', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await DB.getFormattedReviews();
  // data.then(data => console.log(`data2 check ${JSON.stringify(data)}`))
  res.send(data);

});
```

Ultimately I think my limited understanding of Promises/Async/Await & Promise.all failed me a bit here, the Promise.all in the getFormattedReviews was the missing trick.

Some of the code was rewritten with some new Promise syntax which can likely be redacted however I noted when doing this with the getFormattedReviews method that it broke sending the data to the /get-reviews endpoint. Something I'll investigate later.

Answer (score -1):

You are awaiting a callback. I don't think that works.

Try wrapping in a Promise. That might be the issue.

Full disclosure: I did not read your code very in depth...

```
const res = await new Promise(resolve => {
pool.query(getSpecificTherapistReviews, (err, res) => {
    let data = []
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      // console.log(res.rows);
      // step 3
      data = filteringDataForFrontend(res.rows);
    }
    console.log(`\n DEBUG2 - GetSpecificTherapistReviews ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n`)
    resolve(data);
  });
})
```

Comment: I've made a few changes based on that Abraham, however I've hit a new frustrating problem as a result...

Comment: ```
    const res = await new Promise(resolve => {
    pool.query(getDistinct, (err, res) => {
    let data = []
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      // console.log(res.rows);
        async therapist => await getSpecificTherapistReviews(therapist.therapist_name)
        .then(data => console.log(`internal data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)) // data is trapped here -> cant get it out?
      )
    }
    console.log(`\n DEBUG3 - getFormattedReviews data: ${JSON.stringify(data)} \n`)
    resolve(data);
  });
});
  return res;
}
```

Comment: You don't need that .then()
It is an async function.

Simply assign the value you await to a variable.

`const data = await getSpecificTherapistReviews(therapist.therapist_name); 
// console.log(data);`

Comment: No, don't wrap them in `new Promise`. node-postgres methods already return promises - you just have to use them.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. Daniel, simply do not pass any callback whatsoever to `pool.query`. Use `const res = await pool.query(getDistinct)` and then continue your logic. The response is available in `res`